# Strange 5px Margin

Tags: html, css, slider, margin, padding

I am building a website here: [argit.bounde.co.uk](http://www.argit.bounde.co.uk)

I have been searching for hours to try and find the solutions. I am trying to build my own slider which will be fluid width so I cant define height / width where possible. I have got the bulk of the slider working with stock images however when I put elements underneath it they are 5px lower than they are meant to be. This happens in all browsers except IE that I have tested. I want to give the banner which is underneath my slider a negative top margin so that it will display over the slider but until I can figure out what is causing this 5px margin I cant.

The html is here:

```
<div id="slider">
  <div id="sliderwidth">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="imgs/slider/img1.jpg" alt="image 1"></img></li>
      <li><img src="imgs/slider/img2.jpg" alt="image 2"></img></li>
      <li><img src="imgs/slider/img3.jpg" alt="image 3"></img></li>
      <li><img src="imgs/slider/img4.jpg" alt="image 4"></img></li>
    </ul>                           
  </div>                        
</div>  

<div id="sliderborder">
```

Things I have tried:

Removing all jQuery: **didnt work**.
Removing all CSS styling the slider: **didnt work**.
Setting img height to 300px: **didnt work**.
Setting li height to 300px: **worded**.
replacing imgs with divs 300px high: **worked**.
setting padding 0, margin 0 to every element in the slider: **didnt work**.
checked for validation errors: **fully validated**.
checked imgs are 300px high: **they are**. 
checked every element in dev tools to check for any rogue margin/padding: **none found**.

I am literally out of ideas, any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Also, replace your `<img></img>` with just `<img />`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing strange... Just add `display:block` to your images.

By default all images are `inline-elements` (inline or inline-block) and handled as a line of text. This space is where the hanging part of a `y` or `g`would go. This very poorly explained but you get the idea.

```
div#slider ul li img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is a absolut legit solution and not a trick. If i follow your idea why does he set the with to 100%? To change the visual appearance of html is how CSS works.

Comment: @Bondye... it's not a trick, though it would be useful to explain why it works. Images are, by default, `inline-block` elements (`inline` in some browsers). As such, they sit alongside text: the space that's visible is there for descenders on letters like 'p' and 'q'. Setting the `display` property to `block` remedies that. The alternative would be to explicitly set the `vertical-align` property to something other than the default `baseline`. In the case of an image slider like this though, `display: block` seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

just try with

```
div#slider ul img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

or

```
div#slider ul img {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}
```

since, by default, images are inline-block elements so they may need a proper vertical-align setting

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is just add `vertical-align: bottom;` like this:

```
div#slider ul li img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I just had a 5px margin at the top of my website and to the left side. I couldn't get rid of it... until I set the margin on the body element to 0. Problem solved. Hope this helps anyone that comes across this annoying issue. :)