# 4px Gap Below Floated <li> Elements That Contain Images

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following **HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="30x30.gif" /></li>
        <li><img src="30x30.gif" /></li>
        <li><img src="30x30.gif" /></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear: both" />
</div>
```

I want these images to be nicely strung together along the horizontal, so I apply the following **CSS**:

```
div, p, ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

div.container > ul li {
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

This works. However, for some reason there is a 4px gap at the bottom of the `<li>` elements. I know this because I can see a sliver of the yellow background (just at the bottom, not all the way around).

You can see an example of this happening here: http://jsfiddle.net/DBcPw/

**NOTE:** This only seems to happen when the `<li>` elements contain images. If I try it with `<p>` elements instead, the problem doesn't occur.

So, my two questions are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921704/strange-5px-margin/15921929#comment22679963_15921929. You need to set the images themselves to `display: block;`

Comment: Hi @Lorax i think u want to this http://jsfiddle.net/DBcPw/7/

Comment: @RohitAzad: Doesn't work (at least not in Firefox). It just adds a 4px margin around the entire image.

Comment: @Lorax now check to this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/DBcPw/9/

Comment: @Lorax - see the answer I linked to. The space you are seeing is because by default images are `inline-block` elements: they sit alongside text so it is for descenders on letters like 'p' and 'q'.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an update to your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DBcPw/1/)

I added:

```
img{display:block; float:left;}
```

It removes the additional padding and margin that browsers tend to apply to an image to give them some spacing that you might not want. If you want to remove the spacing make them `display :block` and if you want them to sit beside each other then make the images `float:left`.

Comment: There's no need to have `float` in there. Just the `display: block` declaration will do the job. Note also that you could *only* set 'float', as floated elements are all implicitly set to `display: block` as well.

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez I noticed that for this example you dont need to use a float because the images are within an li, but it they were not then the float would be needed. it depends on what needs to be done. but it also does not break the code for this example.

Comment: You're right - the code does the job. Just thought it was worth pointing out that the OP may not want/require a float within a float. Also, I only learned fairly recently about the implied block thing: http://css-tricks.com/implied-block/

Answer (score 1):

The `<img>` tag takes its spacing from the font you're currently using, (white space dependent) so set `font-size: 0;` on the `<li>`s and it will be fine.

```
li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/DBcPw/2/

Comment: Yeah this is right See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940338/is-there-a-way-via-css-to-set-the-image-height-to-the-line-height and +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `li`'s height should match the `img`'s height.

```
div.container > ul li {
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 30px;
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/DBcPw/6/

Comment: That will work, but to my mind it just masks the problem. I want the `li`'s to scale to fit the image, as I can't always guarantee the height of the image.